# Does Index calculus work on secp256k1?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Does Index calculus work on secp256k1?

I did a search but couldn't find answers, Can I use Index calculus to find private key of the elliptic curve secp256k1?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Index Calculus uses smooth numbers in ${F^*}_p$. Elliptic Curve groups do not have a straightforward notion of smoothness & hence Index Calculus does not work in Elliptic Curve groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Index calculus algorithms are more efficient algorithms that make special use of the structure of $(\mathbb{F}_p^\times, \times)$ to solve the discrete logarithm problem in these groups (there are also applications to factoring).
This is to say that they do *not* only use the API of a group, and instead use the special details of the "implementation" of this group.

Algorithms that only use the API of a group are called *generic*, and discrete log problems in any group are vulnerable to them.
For certain groups these generic algorithms are the *best* (known) algorithms.
Elliptic curve groups are the most common class of (thought to be) generic groups used in cryptography.

Comment: Subtitle: this answer's $(\mathbb{F}_p^\times, \times)$ is the [multiplicative group modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) $p$, sometime also noted $\mathbb Z_p^*$ or $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z,*)$.

Comment: Nitpicking, but not all elliptic curve groups are thought to be as hard to attack as generic groups. For example, when a pairing is available, the MOV attack can effectively reduce solving DLOG over the curve to solving DLOG over (the multiplicative subgroup of) a field. Hence, some elliptic curves can actually be attacked by a variant of index calculus (more precisely, MOV + index calculus).

Comment: The structure used in Index Calculus is the notion of smooth numbers in ${F^*}_p$, right?. Elliptic Curve groups do not have a straightforward notion of smoothness & hence Index Calculus does not work in Elliptic Curve groups.